# If marginal PDF is a piecewise function, then conditional expectation will be a piecewise function?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> If marginal PDF is a piecewise function, then conditional expectation will be a piecewise function?

My logic is that if the marginal PDF is piecewise, then the conditional pdf, defined as
$$
f_{Y\vert X}(y\vert x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}
$$
will be piecewise, and therefore the conditional expectation will be piecewise (since $f_X(x)$ depends on what $x$ is).

Here is an example: Consider a triangle with vertices at $(-1,0),(1,0),(0,1)$ and $(X,Y)$ uniformly distributed over this triangle. Then
$$
f_X(x) = \begin{cases} x+1 & \text{ if } -1\leq x <0\\
                    -x+1 & \text{ if } 0\leq x\leq 1
       \end{cases}
$$
and joint density
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 1
$$
so the joint density is piecewise, and therefore in
$$
E(Y\vert X=x) = \int_a^b y f_{Y\vert X}(y\vert x) dy
$$
$f_{Y\vert X}(y\vert x)$ will be different depending on whether $-1\leq x <0$ or
$0\leq x\leq 1$.

Edit: Assume *both* marginal pdfs are piecewise (the example is not like this), therefore both conditional pdfs are piecewise (and it doesn't matter which conditional expectation we are talking about).

Comment: Counterexample: Consider $(X,Y)$ uniformly distributed on the square with vertices $(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm1)$, then both marginals have the PDF $(1-|x|)^+$, which you would probably call "piecewise", but $E(X\mid Y)=E(Y\mid X)=0$, which you would probably not call "piecewise". (Remark: I am not sure you would be able to provide a precise definition of "piecewise" in your context...)

Comment: @Did Thanks for the counterexample; it is helpful. Regarding piecewise, I'm not sure whether I can provide a precise definition or not (if you say not then I probably can't), but your counterexample addresses what I had in mind.